# Does JWT require Access token and refresh token always?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt

IMHO, there are two ways of signing a JWT token in OAuth2.0 - using symmetric hashing algorithm (like HS256) or using asymmetric hashing algorithm (RS256).

If we use asymmetric hashing algorithm such as RS256, do we require access token and refresh token? I believe they are not required as the whatever the claims present in the payload, the resource server can verify independently (as long as it knows the public key of the authorization server).

Then what is the use case for access token and refresh token? Is it required for symmetric hashing only?

Please help me in understanding this better. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The main idea of access token as JWT is that you don't have to go to the Authorization server every time. You can validate it by yourself by checking the signature.  This can remove a lot of traffic from the Authorization server / DB.
You will want to use asymmetric hashing algorithm so the issuer has the private key and he is the only one allowed to issue the tokens and you can check the JWT with the public key.
The refresh token is what validated against a DB and can be revoked.
Every time the access token is expired you use the refresh token to get a new access token from the issuer.

If you plan on going to the Authorization server every time you want to check if the access token is valid, you can use symmetric hashing algorithm but then you miss the point of the JWT - you still have central place for all the authorization requests.

Comment: Thanks Boaz, but I think to verify the claims, you do not require the access token. You can verify the contents by taking the hash of the contents and verifying what is the hash in the signature. What I am trying to understand is what exactly is the purpose of access token.

Comment: Let's take Google for example: after the OAuth handshake you have access token that you can use to call Google APIs (get a file from Google Drive). Google server know if you are allowed to do it is by checking if the access token is valid. It doesn't have to be a JWT, it can be a key that they go to their DB and see if it exists and contain the required permissions. If its a JWT, they can see if the claim contain the user and permissions for that file and the signature match.